# How to get the conflict information like 'tidyverse' package?

Tags: r

During package loading R shows the conflict information which is not in a nice readable shape. Following is the outcome during 'dplyr' loading.

```
library(dplyr)
# Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
# The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
#   filter, lag
# The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
#   intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Is there any way to get the conflict information like 'tidyverse' package?

```
library(tidyverse)
# -- Attaching packages ----------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
# v ggplot2 3.0.0     v purrr   0.2.5
# v tibble  1.4.2     v dplyr   0.7.6
# v tidyr   0.8.1     v stringr 1.3.1
# v readr   1.1.1     v forcats 0.3.0
# -- Conflicts --------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
# x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
# x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Comment: Try `library(conflicted)`, `devtools::install_github("r-lib/conflicted")`, its not exactly same but it is helpful

Comment: Also `conflicts()` isn't bad... and doesn't require any packages

Comment: https://github.com/mkearney/pkgverse